# Can I display increasing memory addresses upwards in gdb

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

In all the stack diagrams of my computer science book, increasing addresses go upwards, as shown in the linked image.
When I experiment with gdb, however, it's the opposite: if I do `x/40b [some memory address here]`, the bytes will be shown "in reading order" and increasing addresses will go downwards.
I find it very confusing to have to switch between the two. Is there a way in gdb to reverse this display?

My OS is a 64-bit Ubuntu if that matters.

[image]

Comment: Might be easier to turn the book upside down :D But yeah, you can script gdb to show stuff reversed. I don't think there is a simple built-in modifier for that.

Comment: @Jester Thank you for your help. Do you know a link (or a section in the gdb manual) about how to "script gdb" ?

Comment: See the [extending gdb section in the manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Extending-GDB.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I find it very confusing

Think of memory as going left to right along the x axis (which is how GDB will display e.g. `x/4x` output), and rotate your book 90 degrees to match this.

You *can* script GDB to print memory backwards, something like:

```
define backwards
  set $j = $arg1
  set $mem = (char*)$arg0
  while $j > 0
    printf "0x%02x ", (unsigned char)$mem[$j--]
  end
  printf "\n"
end

(gdb) backwards 0x4000000 10
```

However, you *shouldn't* do this, because you will only confuse yourself more.